# Consuming JSON object in Jersey service

Tags: json, jersey

I've been Googling my butt off trying to find out how to do this: I have a Jersey REST service. The request that invokes the REST service contains a JSON object. My question is, from the Jersey POST method implementation, how can I get access to the JSON that is in the body of the HTTP request?

Any tips, tricks, pointers to sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks...

--Steve

Comment: am facing the similiar issue. is there any solution to use low-level access to JSONObject?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917516/how-to-consume-a-json-object-via-post-method-from-client/61208366#61208366

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would get at the JSON string itself, but you can certainly get at the data it contains as follows:

Define a JAXB annotated Java class (C) that has the same structure as the JSON object that is being passed on the request.

e.g. for a JSON message:

```
{
  "A": "a value",
  "B": "another value"
}
```

Use something like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class C
{
  public String A;
  public String B;
}
```

Then, you can define a method in your resource class with a parameter of type C. When Jersey invokes your method, the JAXB object will be created based on the POSTed JSON object.

```
@Path("/resource")
public class MyResource
{
  @POST
  public put(C c)
  {
     doSomething(c.A);
     doSomethingElse(c.B);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the JSON string is basically being used more as a dictionary than as a real POJO. I'd rather not have to create a new POJO for the JSON objects.

Comment: Have you looked at using a MessageBodyReader (http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html). Not tried it myself, but you might be able to get in at that level and convert the JSON stream to a map etc.

Comment: Actually it turns out that its much simpler than I thought. I can get the body of the HTTP request as a string argument, and then process it using any JSON library (currently using Google GSON) to convert the request data into local objects.

Answer (score 16):

As already suggested, changing the `@Consumes` Content-Type to `text/plain` will work, but it doesn't seem right from an REST API point of view.

Imagine your customer having to POST JSON to your API but needing to specify the Content-Type header as `text/plain`. It's not clean in my opinion. In simple terms, if your API accepts JSON then the request header should specify `Content-Type: application/json`.

In order to accept JSON but serialize it into a `String` object rather than a POJO you can implement a custom [MessageBodyReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html). Doing it this way is just as easy, and you won't have to compromise on your API spec.

It's worth reading the docs for [MessageBodyReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) so you know exactly how it works. This is how I did it:

**Step 1. Implement a custom [MessageBodyReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html)**

```
@Provider
@Consumes("application/json")
public class CustomJsonReader<T> implements MessageBodyReader<T> {
  @Override
  public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
      Annotation[] annotations,MediaType mediaType) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public T readFrom(Class<T> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
      MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
      InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

    /* Copy the input stream to String. Do this however you like.
     * Here I use Commons IOUtils.
     */
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(entityStream, writer, "UTF-8");
    String json = writer.toString();

    /* if the input stream is expected to be deserialized into a String,
     * then just cast it
     */
    if (String.class == genericType)
      return type.cast(json);

    /* Otherwise, deserialize the JSON into a POJO type.
     * You can use whatever JSON library you want, here's
     * a simply example using GSON.
     */
    return new Gson().fromJson(json, genericType);
  }
}
```

The basic concept above is to check if the input stream is expected to be converted to a `String` (specified by `Type genericType`). If so, then simply cast the JSON into the specified `type` (which will be a `String`). If the expected type is some sort of POJO, then use a JSON library (e.g. Jackson or GSON) to deserialize it to a POJO.

**Step 2. Bind your [MessageBodyReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html)**

This depends on what framework you're using. I find that Guice and Jersey work well together. Here's how I bind my [MessageBodyReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) in Guice:

In my [JerseyServletModule](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/contribs/jersey-guice/com/sun/jersey/guice/JerseyServletModule.html) I bind the reader like so --

```
bind(CustomJsonReader.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

The above `CustomJsonReader` will deserialize JSON payloads into POJOs as well as, if you simply want the raw JSON, `String` objects.

The benefit of doing it this way is that it will accept `Content-Type: application/json`. In other words, your request handler can be set to consume JSON, which seems proper:

```
@POST
@Path("/stuff")
@Consumes("application/json") 
public void doStuff(String json) {
  /* do stuff with the json string */
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Jersey supports low-level access to the parsed JSONObject using the Jettison types JSONObject and JSONArray.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
    <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8</version>
</dependency>
```

For example:

```
{
  "A": "a value",
  "B": "another value"
}


@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public void doStuff(JSONObject json) {
  /* extract data values using DOM-like API */
  String a = json.optString("A");
  Strong b = json.optString("B");
  return;
}
```

See the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19.1/json.html#json.low.level.approach.section) for more examples.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get...
    `Unrecognized field "A" (class org.json.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable`
...and if I add the following...
`mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`
...Then the object comes through empty `{}`

Comment: this is not work. i am getting 415 error. Is there any solution and what dependency to be added for low level json access?

Answer (score 7):

This gives you access to the raw post.

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes("text/plain") 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String processRequset(String pData) {
    // do some stuff, 
    return someJson;
}
```

Comment: This was a slick, easy way to pass JSON from my client and not have the server/client need to know about the objects that I am passing. I just used GSON to serialize it out and attach it to the post. Worked great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Submit/POST the form/HTTP.POST with a parameter with the JSON as the value.

@QueryParam jsonString

public  desolveJson(jsonString)

Comment: I thought about doing that. It's just not quite the way I'd like to go. There are a few toolkits out there that drop the complete JSON into the actual body of the HTTP request, and I'd like to follow that pattern if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers say a service function must use `consumes=text/plain` but my Jersey version is fine with `application/json` type. Jackson and Jersey version is
`jackson-core=2.6.1, jersey-common=2.21.0`.

```
@POST
@Path("/{name}/update/{code}")
@Consumes({ "application/json;charset=UTF-8" })
@Produces({ "application/json;charset=UTF-8" })
public Response doUpdate(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @PathParam("name") String name, 
      @PathParam("code") String code, String reqBody) {
  System.out.println(reqBody);

  StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
    @Override public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
      ..my fanzy custom json stream writer..
    }
  };

  CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
  cc.setNoCache(true);
  return Response.ok().type("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    .cacheControl(cc).entity(stream).build();
}
```

Client submits `application/json` request with a json request body. Servlet code may parse string to JSON object or save as-is to a database.

Answer (score 0):

**SIMPLE SOLUTION:**

If you just have a simple JSON object coming to the server and you **DON'T** want to create a new POJO (java class) then just do this.

The JSON I am sending to the server

```
{
    "studentId" : 1
}
```

The server code:

```
    //just to show you the full name of JsonObject class
    import javax.json.JsonObject; 

    @Path("/")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response deleteStudent(JsonObject json) {
        //Get studentId from body <-------- The relevant part 
        int studentId = json.getInt("studentId");
        
        //Return something if necessery
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```