# Jersey application/json to parameters

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I want to send from my client-side application/json request with JSON

`{ "content" : "My content", "question" : "WHY?" }`

Is there some way in Jersey rest for retrieve this JSON on server side my some method like:

```
@POST
@Path("/myMethod")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void myServerMethod(@FormParam("content") String content, @FormParam("question") String question) {
         System.out.println(content+" "+question);
}
```

Now i can't retrieve values from json's body.

Best regards

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662490/consuming-json-object-in-jersey-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make an object representing your post data:

```
public class MyPostData
{
    private String content;
    private String question;

    // getters and setters here
}
```

Then, change your resource method to:

```
@POST
@Path("/myMethod")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void myServerMethod(MyPostData data)
{
    System.out.println(data.getContent() + " " + data.getQuestion());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know, that i can use class for retrieve application/json. But i don't want to create separate class for this purpose.

Comment: Ah ok. Are you using either Jackson, Moxy, or Jettison as a JSON library with Jersey? If so you can make the first method parameter a `JsonObject` (which will differ based on the json lib you are using) and pull the strings from that